# Javascript Function for Highlighting something at certain time of day

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a spreadsheet that displays every member of my staff's name and what time their lunch break is. We use this list to assign them new cases that come in, but obviously we can't assign them a case when they are at lunch.

I would like to figure out a way to highlight or "gray out" their names when they're on lunch, and then change back when their lunch time is over.

Comment: Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You gotta give a lot more details about your problem first. What library are you using to render your spreadsheet? That would be a good start. Have you tried reading their docs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a conditional class with css and JavaScript maybe inside window.onLoad.. Something like that:

CSS:

```
.class{
...
}

.classHighLight{
...
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var currentHour = new Date().getHours();
   var arrStaffs = Here you load your spreadsheet's hours

   arrStaffs.forEach((member) => {
       if(member.lunchHour == currentHour){
           document.getElementById(*Member's button ID*).className = 'classHighLight';
       }
   })
};
```

That way, when you visit the page, your onLoad function will highligth members that have the same lunchHour as the current hour. I dont't know your spreadsheet data layout, but I'm pretending you have something like:

Mike - 14 / Peter - 12

Hope it helps you :)